# Create React App image imports incorrectly: fetching url relative to path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I'm using Create React App and React-Router.

I import and use an image like this in `<Component>`:

```js
import icon from "./Media/icon.png";

<img src={icon} />
```

I also have a react-router route above this.

The interesting thing is, when running locally (`npm start`), and inspecting the network,
loading the images always fetches the url `localhost/static/media/icon...png`

However, when hosting (`npm build`), the imported image path is relative to the react-router path.
Eg, if the user is at `/path`, then rendering `<Component>` tries to fetch `localhost/path/static/media/icon...png` (Which doesn't exist, and gives a 404).

How do I make sure importing an image will render correctly regardless of the path they're at? And why does the issue only come up in a build?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Not the most elegant way but you can move your media folder into the public folder and try ```<img scr={process.env.PUBLIC_URL+”Media/yourimg.png”}/>``` instead of importing the image

Comment: in your code you use capital M for Media the error given path is small m for media

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the issue. When deployed, the react-router path ("path") is prepended to the image url, which is causing the 404. If I manually ommit the prepended path, the image is found correctly.